# Javascript Partial Initialization

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I know `Typescript` has partial initialization like this:

```
class Example {
    name: string;
    lastname: string;
    
    constructor(init?:Partial<Example>){
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}
```

And I was wondering if `Javascript` has something similar, or what could I do to achieve something like that.

Comment: Searching for `class Example { constructor( { name = "", lastname ="" } = {} ) { // your stuff }  }` ?

Comment: Removing the types, this _is_ JavaScript?